# Запросы из Vue на сервер через vhost.conf (Nginx)

Tags: vue.js, nginx, proxy, proxypass

Есть проект фронта на Vue. Запросы на сервер проксируются с помощью файла Nginx_1.21_vhost.conf, который лежит в /dist.

Nginx_1.21_vhost.conf:

```
server {
listen                    %ip%:8080;
listen                    %ip%:%httpsport% ssl;
server_name               %host% %aliases%;
root                      '%hostdir%';
#limit_conn               addr 64;
autoindex                 off;
index                     index.php index.html index.htm;

ssl_certificate           '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.crt';
ssl_certificate_key       '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.key';
#ssl_trusted_certificate  '';

# Force HTTPS
#if ($scheme ~* ^(?!https).*$) {
#    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#}

# Force www.site.com => site.com
#if ($host ~* ^www\.(.+)$) {
#    return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri;
#}

# Disable MIME sniffing
add_header X-Content-Type-Options 'nosniff' always;

# HSTS
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=2592000' always;

# Disable access to hidden files/folders
location ~* /\.(?!well-known/) {
    deny all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# Disable access to backup/config/command/log files
location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|co?nf(ig)?|in[ci]|log|sh|sql|tar|t?gz)|~)$ {
    deny all;
}

location /callback/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Server-Name' 'cloud host';
    proxy_pass http://бэк/callback/;
}

location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://бэк/client/;
}
..........
```

**Проблема** - в папке dist лежит build и обновляется, соответственно, по команде npm run build. Во время разработки неудобно билдить после каждого изменения, поэтому запускается npm run serve. Но в таком случае, Nginx_1.21_vhost.conf уже не работает и запросы не отправляются.
Можно ли использовать Nginx_1.21_vhost.conf при запуске Vue проекта через команду npm run serve?

*ОС: Windows*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что нельзя использовать Nginx_1.21_vhost.conf. Тут может помочь плагин `http-proxy-middleware`, который настроит прокси-перенаправление запросов.

Comment: Чем плагин `http-proxy-middleware` отличается от модуля `http-proxy-middleware`?